# Set an image as a background on a circle

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a some local images such as calendar.svg, I have about 10 of these SVG images, I want to append them to the background of some circles.

There's a way to do it using patterns which uses a lot of code! I was wondering if there was a quick and easy way to just use the local images!

what my code looks like:

The first two blocks of circle code are me appending patterns, using that method for the images, but the third and final block is me trying to actually just access the local image and use that, but this isnt working!

```
  circle
    .filter(node => node.depth !== 0 && node.type === EngagementType.Event)
    .append('circle')
    .classed('Engagement-GraphNode', true)
    .classed('Engagement-GraphNodeBackground', true)
    .classed('Engagement-GraphLeaf', node => node && (node.depth === 4 && !node.isExtraNode))
    .style('fill', d => `url(#insightImageEvents-${d.id})`)
    .style('opacity', node => (node.visible) ? 1 : 0)
    .style('visibility', node => (node.visible) ? 'visible' : 'hidden')
    .on('click', node => onClick(node));
  circle
    .filter(node => !node.parent)
    .append('circle')
    .classed('Engagement-GraphNode', true)
    .classed('Engagement-GraphNodeBackground', true)
    .classed('Engagement-GraphLeaf', node => node && (node.depth === 4 && !node.isExtraNode))
    .style('fill', node => 'white')
    .style('opacity', node => (node.visible) ? 1 : 0)
    .style('visibility', node => (node.visible) ? 'visible' : 'hidden')
    .on('click', node => onClick(node));
  circle
    .filter(node => node.name === 'Annual Meetings')
    .append("svg:image")
    .attr('width', 20)
    .attr('height', 24)
    .attr("xlink:href", "/calendar.svg") <---- trying
    // .classed('Engagement-GraphNode', true)
    // .classed('Engagement-GraphNodeBackground', true)
    // .classed('Engagement-GraphLeaf', node => node && (node.depth === 4 && !node.isExtraNode))
    // .style('fill', node => 'red')
    .style('opacity', node => (node.visible) ? 1 : 0)
    .style('visibility', node => (node.visible) ? 'visible' : 'hidden')
    .on('click', node => onClick(node));
```

any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score -1):

You can use image masking to achieve this as such:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
    <defs>
        <mask id="image-mask">
            <circle id="outer" cx="50" cy="50" r="50" fill="white"/>
            <circle id="inner" cx="50" cy="50" r="25"/>
        </mask>
    </defs>
    <image width="100%" height="100%" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" xlink:href="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1472195870936-d88b0d4c1b41?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=85&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=srgb&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjE0NTg5fQ%3D%3D&s=f1abbd4d59a9b448813cb48769806ada" mask="url(#image-mask)"></image>
</svg>
```